# How to detach from dtach when the detach character is disabled

Tags: bash, signals, dtach

I am using [dtach](https://github.com/crigler/dtach) like this: `dtach -A /tmp/mysession -Ez bash`. This starts `bash`. Now, how do I detach from dtach? I have disabled the detach character using the `-E` option, so I cannot press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>\</kbd>  to detach. The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dtach) says:

> -E
>
> Disables the detach character. dtach does not try to scan input from the terminal for a detach character. The only way to detach from the session is then by sending the attaching process an appropriate signal.

The man page doesn't specify what the "appropriate signal" is. How exactly do I detach from within bash when the detach character is disabled?

I tried `kill -SIGHUP $$`, but that always terminates `dtach` (`[EOF - dtach terminating]`) instead of detaching.

Comment: Using the `SIGHUP` signal works for me. Are you sure you are sending the signal to dtach itself and not its child process?